# Dyldinfo commamd not found

Tags: ios, macos

mac os 10.13.4

I write the command 'dyldinfo' in shell, but is wroing
**-bash: dyldinfo: command not found**

[image]

hope you help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make sure you have either [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) or [Command Line Tools](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/) installed.

If you have one of those, you can find **dyldinfo** in **/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin**.
So, to run it, type this into your **bash**:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/dyldinfo
```

Answer (score 4):

On recent versions of macOS you can run the tool with `xcrun dyldinfo` (as long as you have Xcode installed)

Answer (score 1):

You can check the `dyldinfo` path using following command:

```
$ xcrun --sdk dyldinfo

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/dyldinfo
```

Showing that the command `dyldinfo` is under the path:`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/dyldinfo`, which means commands like `dyldinfo` belong to Toolchains of Xcode. Therefore, 'dyldinfo' cannot be used as a separate shell command. Instead, you must invoke it by using `xcrun <sdk>`.

```
$ xcrun dyldinfo

Usage: dyldinfo [-arch <arch>] <options> <mach-o file>
    -dylibs           print dependent dylibs
    -dr               print dependent dylibs and show any recorded DR info
    -rebase           print addresses dyld will adjust if file not loaded at preferred address
    -bind             print addresses dyld will set based on symbolic lookups
    -weak_bind        print symbols which dyld must coalesce
    -lazy_bind        print addresses dyld will lazily set on first use
    -export           print addresses of all symbols this file exports
    -opcodes          print opcodes used to generate the rebase and binding information
    -function_starts  print table of function start addresses
    -export_dot       print a GraphViz .dot file of the exported symbols trie
    -data_in_code     print any data-in-code information
```